Cannot assign requested address
Есть скрипт на python, который собирает данные из API и выгружает их в google-таблицу.
На локальной машине все работает без проблем. При запуске сервера, в момент первого обращения к API возникает ошибка "Cannot assign requested address". В чем может быть проблема и какие могут быть способы ее решения?

Полный стек-трейс ошибки в вопрос. Чтобы было хотя бы понятно, какой код эту ошибку кидает. Да и сам код, имеющий отношение к вопросу, не помешал бы.

Конкретно строка, которая вызывает ошибку
async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=data) as response:
Не стал прикреплять только потому, что с ПК этот код отрабатывает без подобной ошибки

Ну мало ли что где-то отрабатывает. У вас в конкретном случае не работает, значит должен быть в вопросе код и стек-трейс.
